# Man not sure whether he released gas

Tags: salat

A man was praying Asr. During and before prayer he kept his anus open. So there is a possibility for gas to exit. However throughout his salah he didn't feel any gas being released but during the final tashahud he felt something in his rear ( a kind of 'tic' feeling ,not sound (you know the feeling you get when you hit something and it gives a 'tic' sound but here there was no sound only sensation.  (he is not sure whether it is gas or movement of his clothes or something else )

In this case I have two questions

1.Is his prayer valid  ?

2.Should we block the anus while we are in wudu until we finish prayer ?

PS: Don't say " if you are certain "  because I am fed up of reading that statement over a dozen times .
Just say whether this man's prayer is valid or not .He is not at least 50% sure whether he released gas

Answer (score -1):

From consensus, it is haram, and you should stop your prayer. If it is n a public place, you should apologize to the people and move outside of the building. I recommend that you reach out to Allah (SWT) and you repent to him while moving away, redoing wudu and praying again. This even applies if in doubt.

This is not declared from any surah/ayah/hadith that I can find. It seems to be the consensus